# Why is prototype object of a newly created object, a constructor and not Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript

Prototype for my newly created object, i.e. `let testObject = {}`, is a constructor. Why it isn't `Object` or `Object.prototype`?

Comment: It's prototype is `Object` which is a constructor

Comment: `testObject.__proto__.__proto__` gives `null`, which suggests that `Object`, which is constructor, and not an object, is the last link in the prototypal inheritance?

Comment: The prototype of `testObject` is `Object.prototype`, what makes you say it's a constructor? (try: `Object.getPrototypeOf(testObject) === Object.prototype`)

Comment: @NickParsons, are you replying to me or to @Konrad?

Comment: @user21998780 To you mainly (you mentioned in your question that the prototype is a constructor, so I'm wondering what's making you say that it's a constructor and not Object.prototype)

Comment: @NickParsons, when I to `testObject.__proto__` I get `{constructor: f, __defineGetter__: f, ... }`

Comment: `testObject.__proto__.constructor` is a constructor

Comment: @user21998780 Yeah, so that's an object (specifically `Object.prototype`), it isn't a constructor. Constructors are functions, just because an object has a `constructor` property on it doesn't make it a constructor. You can see that your prototype is in fact `Object.prototype` by doing `testObject.__proto__ === Object.prototype`

Comment: "`testObject.__proto__` I get `{constructor: f, __defineGetter__: f, ... }`", which tells you that `testObject.__proto__` HAS a `constructor`, not `testObject.__proto__` IS a `constructor`. `testObject.__proto__.constructor` is the `constructor`